# Immigration officer placed a standard Leave to Enter stamp when I have Indefinite Leave to Remain. What do I do?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps, uk-residents

I travel on a NZ passport and have lived in the UK since 2006. I travelled to Canada in June 2016 to begin a 2 year Canadian working visa but on a trip back to the UK in July I received a 6 month visa stamp in my passport despite having an Indefinite Leave To Remain Visa in my old passport (I haven't got a biometric card yet but plan to apply for one before I return to the UK to live.
What should I do about this?[image]

Comment: Is there a chance your extended residence outside the UK terminated your indefinite leave to remain?

Comment: No, that only happens if you are away for a 2 year period. I returned after a year.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie it shouldnt have done - the period of automatic cancellation is 2 years outside the UK, after which you need to apply for a Returning Resident Visa.  The OP has only been out of the UK for just over a year.

Comment: @LeighMcAlpine did you present your old passport with the ILR stamp?

Comment: I did. I travel in and out of the UK all the time so assumed it would be the same and I'd just get the standard entry stamp.

Comment: @LeighMcAlpine did the immigration official look at your old passport?

Comment: Maybe this question is more suited to expats.stackexchange.com? But regardless, this is an extremely bad situation to be in. You should strongly consider contacting an experienced immigration solicitor as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm in Canada now until June or longer if I can extend my visa somehow. I cannot go back to Gatwick. I'll have to go to the Consulate in Calgary.

Answer (score 2):

I'd contact the Duty CIO or HM Inspector at Gatwick and explain the error to them. You will be called back to Gatwick and the endorsement will be amended. The Home Office Referred Casework Unit at Lunar House only deals with entry clearance/ visa amendments but the incident happened at the Port of Entry and therefore you need to contact Border Force at Gatwick. Next time make sure the IO looks at your expired passport and endorses the free standing date stamp with VIPP.

Comment: In case anyone doesn't know, 'VIPP'  (see above) means 'Visa in previous passport'